Can't get the pandas style.hide() method to work properly
I want to be able to hide certain rows/columns from my styled Dataframe post-styling.
This is how my dataframe/style object currently looks, and is produced by the below code
data = {
    'site': ['Brighton', 'London', 'Manchester', 'Leicester'],
    'wait_time': [10, 15, 20, 25],
    'wait_time_change_percent': [5, 10, -5, 0],
    'calls': [100, 150, 120, 130],
    'calls_change_percent': [10, -5, 20, 15],
    'complaints': [5, 10, 15, 20],
    'complaints_change_percent': [5, 10, -5, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('site')

def color_change(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return f'color: {color}'

df_styled = df.style.applymap(lambda val: color_change(val), subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['wait_time_change_percent', 'calls_change_percent', 'complaints_change_percent']])

I've made this a lot simpler than my actual code just for example purposes so pls don't ask me to use a different method as there's a reason I have to remove the columns after the styling and not before :)
Now I thought I could use hide() by inserting this line:
df_styled_hidden = df_styled.hide(subset=['wait_time', 'calls', 'complaints'], axis=1) 
But when I go to write df_styled_hidden, it just looks exactly the same as my screenshot. Is this a bug with style.hide() or am I just using it incorrectly? Thanks!

I can't reproduce your issue, this works well for me (pandas 2.2.2).

Weird! I'm using pandas 2.1.4

That's an open issue (see GH7007).
One of the workarounds is to pass the difference as a column_order of st.dataframe :
to_hide = ["wait_time", "calls", "complaints"]

st.dataframe(df_styled, column_order=df.columns.difference(to_hide).tolist())

Or, use columns' config :
to_hide = ["wait_time", "calls", "complaints"]

st.dataframe(df_styled, column_config=dict.fromkeys(to_hide, None))



Ah ok thanks, that's a shame as I wanted to be able to filter out rows too and can't see a workaround for this.

If you're ok with using markdown : st.markdown(df_styled.hide(subset=["wait_time", "calls", "complaints"], axis=1).hide(subset=["London"], axis=0).to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True).
